# Emacs: как вызвать Лисп функцию из консоли не открывая редактора?

Tags: linux, lisp, emacs

Как вызвать свою функцию из командной строки через редактор Emacs уже знаю, это написано [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112256/emacs-custom-command-line-argument), но при этом сам редактор так же открывается и в своем буфере выводит результат функции, 
Мне же нужно, чтобы редактор не открывался, а выводил результат прямо в консоль.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть ключи  `--eval` и `--batch`

```
emacs --batch --eval "(+ 1 1)"
emacs --batch --eval "(print (+ 1 1))"
```

**Ссылки**

- https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Batch-Mode.html

Comment: Наверное не любой. У меня `GNU Emacs 25.2.2` никакой 2-ки не выводит

Comment: @avp да, он просто считает. Если вывод нужно выплюнуть думаю `print` нужен.

Comment: Да, получилось.